# Include HTML Page into another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I'm trying to show a page into a jquery dialog.
I'm using D3.js also.

So i'm getting data like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html><head><meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/> 
<link href="/g2-web-ui/resources/images/icon_mobile/ios7/Icon-76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http equiv="Content-Type"/>
 ...
```

As you can see it's a hole page.

How can I show that in my jquery dialog ?

Comment: There are a lot of options.  You could dump the HTML into the dialog widget wholesale, use an iframe, glean specific tags, etc.  What have you tried?  What didn't work?

Comment: I tried with $('').html(code) but I got import error, i'll try he iframe option

Comment: You can use [jQuery Load() Method](http://api.jquery.com/load/).